# Remove button when click itselt in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

Hello I have a custom `UIButton` has added. And I want to remove this button when click on it self. I have done like this.

```
    btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCoveringPerson(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnDelete.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "close-dark"), for: .normal)
    btnCoveringPerson.addSubview(btnDelete)
```

And this is my delete button selector

```
func deleteCoveringPerson(sender:UIButton)
{
    dm.strCoveringPersonNAme=""
    dm.strcoveringPersonCode="0"
    btnCoveringPerson.setTitle(lan.getConvertedLanguageString(word: "COVERINGPERSON"), for: .normal)
    btnDelete.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @ReinierMelian My button is not removing. But its calling the delete method

Comment: Call sender.removeFromSuperview() in deleteCoveringPerson() method.

Comment: @Amit yeas this worked for me :)

Comment: @Amit but it doesnt work once I go to another view controller and then click on it

Comment: By calling removeFromSuperView on the button you are actually deallocating the button. So either you have to reallocate or simply Hide the button by calling "sender.isHidden = true" instead of removing FromSuperView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this work just fine

```
func deleteCoveringPerson(sender:UIButton)
{
    dm.strCoveringPersonNAme=""
    dm.strcoveringPersonCode="0"
    btnCoveringPerson.setTitle(lan.getConvertedLanguageString(word: "COVERINGPERSON"), for: .normal)
    sender.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But I have a small problem,, when I go to another viewcontroller and comes back and then if I clicked then it doesnt remove. Why is that?

Comment: check if you are adding target again and if your method is called, if is called then must be removed @user1960169